# Rails: Selecting unique label values with its ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have a table in which `labels` are not unique with unique ids, How to select unique `labels` with any ids associated with it.

```
@questionnaireload = Questionnaire.select("DISTINCT label","id")
```

but this gives me

```
#<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Questionnaire label: "Closet", id: 4>, #<Questionnaire label: "Styling", id: 1>, #<Questionnaire label: "Freestyle", id: 5>, #<Questionnaire label: "Styling", id: 2>]>
```

I want either `<Questionnaire label: "Styling", id: 1>` or `<Questionnaire label: "Styling", id: 2>` not both, 
I looked upon pluck, but this also not helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this, try to the following

```
Questionnaire.select('DISTINCT on (label) label, id')
```

It won't work if you use `sqlite3` but it works [`postgresql`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT)

Comment: yes i am using postgresql as well, and thank you it worked

Comment: Have you helped with my answer?

Comment: I already upvoted your answer, since my repo is 14 so it hasn't reflected in UI. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

Try the below query, I think it should work. Passed the arguments in an array, since it was through wrong arguments error.

```
@questionnaireload = Questionnaire.select(['DISTINCT label', 'id']).uniq_by { |obj| obj.label }
```